# Populate table from another query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, insert

So I have a SQL query that gives me a list of ints. Listed here:

```
select distinct
            re_entity_id
      from cfo_transaction 
            inner join cfo_tran_quote  ON tq_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id
            inner join cfo_trans_entity_rel on te_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id and te_rv_rel_type_id in (713,715)
            inner join com_entity on te_co_re_entity_id = re_entity_id
      where 
            dbo.islmsloan(tq_tran_quote_id) = 1
            and isnull(re_fictitious_bit,0) = 0
```

This gives me a list of id's that I need to insert into another table along with other stuff. The other table looks like this:

```
ens_engine_sponsor_id - PK
ens_rs_sponsor_id - relates to the id from the other query
ens_use_new_models_bit - should always be 1 for each insert
ens_start_dt - should be 09/05/2011 for every one
ens_end_dt - should be null for every one
```

How would I formulate something that automatically inserts a row for each of those Id's in this new table with the given criteria? (Not so good with SQL...)

Thanks

Comment: 09/05/2011 is 9 May or 5 September?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add constants into your `SELECT` list as below.

```
insert into othertable
            (ens_rs_sponsor_id,
             ens_use_new_models_bit,
             ens_start_dt)
select distinct re_entity_id,
                1,
                '20110905'
from   cfo_transaction
       inner join cfo_tran_quote
         ON tq_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id
       inner join cfo_trans_entity_rel
         on te_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id
            and te_rv_rel_type_id in ( 713, 715 )
       inner join com_entity
         on te_co_re_entity_id = re_entity_id
where  dbo.islmsloan(tq_tran_quote_id) = 1
       and isnull(re_fictitious_bit, 0) = 0
```

If the reason for using `DISTINCT` is to remove duplicates brought in by the joins you could consider using `WHERE EXISTS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether ens_engine_sponsor_id is an identity field but assuming it is then you can do this.

```
    INSERT INTO MyTableName(
        ens_rs_sponsor_id,      
        ens_use_new_models_bit,
        ens_start_dt,
        ens_end_dt)
select distinct 
            re_entity_id,
            1,
            '09 May 2011',
            NULL
      from cfo_transaction  
            inner join cfo_tran_quote  ON tq_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id 
            inner join cfo_trans_entity_rel on te_tr_transaction_id = tr_transaction_id and te_rv_rel_type_id in (713,715) 
            inner join com_entity on te_co_re_entity_id = re_entity_id 
      where  
            dbo.islmsloan(tq_tran_quote_id) = 1 
            and isnull(re_fictitious_bit,0) = 0
```